How to remove personal email from git commits after PR has been merged?
On GitHub I've successfully opened a PR on a public repository, which has been recently merged:
My Pull Request (#25)
* Feature 1
* Feature 2
* Bump version

---------

Authored-by: My Username <my.personal@email.me>

My issue is that my personal email is now public available, which is a thing that I absolutely don't want to.
Is there a way to hide it somehow?
So far I tried:

Set my email private on GitHub settings
Tried git config --global user.email "12345678+username@users.noreply.github.com"

BONUS: I've read that maybe amend might do the trick but still the procedure isn't clear to me. Would it work even on editing infos from already merged commits?
Lastly, do the maintainers of the public repository have the power to change such displayed infos?

You make a copy of a physical letter. You send the original to Almaty, Kazakhstan. You can change the copy all you want. You can’t change what you wrote on the original letter.


How to remove personal email from git commits

You cannot do this.
Git allows you to write new commits and re-hang labels so the labels now point to those new commits instead of the old ones, that's normal, but it is simply not possible (not as an authority thing, this is a "because math" thing) to actually alter existing history. New history will have a different id.
So git commit --amend writes a new commit with any alterations you like to snapshot, ancestry, message and/or author/committer or timestamps, and re-hangs your branch-tip label on this new commit, abandoning the old one in your current repository. The old commit is still there. Git will eventually get around to garbage-collecting it if it's unreachable through any other reference or reflog for long enough and the repo looks to Git's quick checks like it could use a nice tidy-up.
You particularly can't do this in other people's repositories. Their repositories are theirs, you send a letter to someone, that letter is theirs. It's not yours any more. You have no, zero, not any, zip, zilch, no way to alter the histories in their repositories that they don't go out of their way to set up for you.
The most you can do is ask them to abandon your mistakenly-pushed history, and hope nobody has fetched it into their own repositories in the meantime.  If you've got force-push rights to the branches they merged your history to you can do the abandoning yourself, but for instance I think GitHub keeps a record of PR tips, and I'm not 100% certain but I think you'll have to have personal assistance from GitHub staff to erase those.
Pushing to a public repo is publishing on a globally-accessible hosted server explicitly intended for global redistribution. Probably best you just treat this as "lesson learned".

You're right, touché

Yes, amending could help in the general case, but probably not here.
Since it's been merged, you would need to ask the owners of the repository to amend the merge commit with different metadata and force-push the main branch.
I doubt they're willing to do that, because that will cause diverging histories for people who have already cloned from that main branch, etc – in short, a lot of pain.

do the maintainers of the public repository have the power to change such displayed infos?

As discussed above, they have the power to change the commits in their repo, which is where that data is stored, but any clones of that repo will still have the old data.

Additionally, even old versions of web sites (including software repos) are often copied/cached/archived in multiple places, systematically and spontaneously. It is basically impossible to remove information from the internet that once has been part of it.

I've successfully amended my commits in my branch, updating my email with a .noreply. As expected the final PR message remains unchanged

The branch doesn't matter, since it's merged already. If changes in your personal branches affected the merged history, that would be a catastrophe all around.

Oh, and looking at the commit in question, it's a squash merge commit (and it's a Co-authored-by: line in the commit message, by the way), so your original commits don't matter at all.
